# Data Concurrency in SQL Server or c#.net

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, concurrency, ado.net

I am building a dynamic web application(asp.net /c#.net) that uses SQL Server. As I was testing my web application I notice that if two users insert or update information at the same time using the same table it causes the saved information to be placed in different record location.

For example,

when user 1 and user 2 insert an image, user 1 is trying to insert an image called 'abc' and user 2  is trying to insert another image called '123' at the same time. After is saved, user 1 sees in their end '123' and user 2 sees 'abc'.

I was looking around and I came across the term Data Concurrency and it seems this could fix this problem. But, I don't know how to accomplish this. I would like to know first where is the best practice do a data concurrency in the database side or in the c#.net side and why?

Furthermore, where is a good tutorial that I can learn more about implementing Data Concurrency on c#.net or sql server

This is a simple code how I get information from the database using c#.net:

I have a table class called OAccount and I make sure it has the same columns in the database.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections;

 namespace lktec.Objects
 {
     public class OAccount
     {
         public int SysNo{get;set;}
         public string AccountNo { get; set; }
         public DateTime RegistDate{get;set;}
         public string AccountName { get; set; }
         public string PassWord { get; set; }
         public int Status { get; set; }
         public int CountrySysNo { get; set; }
         public int StateSysNo { get; set; }
         public int CitySysNo { get; set; }
         public string ZipCode{get;set;}
         public string Address { get; set; }
         public string WebSite { get; set; }
         public int Type { get; set; }
         public int ShipBy { get; set; }
         public DateTime Inputdate { get; set; }
         public DateTime LstInputdate { get; set; }
         public Boolean StateIsString { get; set; }
         public Boolean CityIsString { get; set; }
         public string State { get; set; }
         public string City { get; set; }

         public OAccount()
         {
             this.SysNo = _.Default.IntNull;
             this.AccountNo = _.Default.StringNull;
             this.RegistDate = _.Default.DateTimeNull;
             this.AccountName = _.Default.StringNull;
             this.PassWord = _.Default.StringNull;
             this.Status = _.Default.IntNull;
             this.CountrySysNo = _.Default.IntNull;
             this.StateSysNo = _.Default.IntNull;
             this.CitySysNo = _.Default.IntNull;
             this.ZipCode = _.Default.StringNull;
             this.Address = _.Default.StringNull;
             this.WebSite = _.Default.StringNull;
             this.ShipBy =1;
             this.Inputdate = _.Default.DateTimeNull;
             this.LstInputdate = _.Default.DateTimeNull;
             this.StateIsString =false;
             this.CityIsString = false;

             this.State = _.Default.StringNull;
             this.City = _.Default.StringNull;
         }
     }
 }
```

I have another class for my queries:

```
 using System;
 using lktec.Objects;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
 using __ = lktec.Utils;


 namespace lktec.Sql
 {
     public class SAccount : OAccount
    {
      public DataSet GetAccounts(SortedList paramList)
         {
             string sql = "SELECT a.*,(select Country_Name from World_Country where SysNo=a.CountrySysNo) Country,case when StateIsString=1 then State else (select State_Name from World_State where SysNo=a.StateSysNo) end StateName,case when CityIsString=1 then City else (select City_Name from World_City where SysNo=a.CitySysNo) end CityName,b.CreditLimt,b.CurrentPaymentReceivable,(select top 1 c.repname from rep c where c.AccountSysNo=a.sysno) RepName,(select top 1 PaymentName from PaymentType where SysNo=b.PaymentTermSysNo) PaymentTerm FROM Account a left join PaymentTerm b on a.sysNo=b.AccountSysNo WHERE EXISTS(SELECT c.* FROM Account_Contact c where a.SysNo=c.AccountSysNo @filter) and 1=1 ";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sFilter = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string key in paramList.Keys)
        {
            sb.Append(" AND ");
            object item = paramList[key];

            switch (key)
            {
                case "ContactName":
                    sFilter.Append(" and c.ContactName").Append(" LIKE ").Append(_.Util.ToSqlLikeString(item.ToString()));
                    break;
                case "Email":
                    sFilter.Append(" and c.Email").Append(" LIKE ").Append(_.Util.ToSqlLikeString(item.ToString()));
                    break;
                case "Phone":
                    sFilter.Append(" and c.Phone").Append(" LIKE ").Append(_.Util.ToSqlLikeString(item.ToString()));
                    break;
                case "Mobile":
                    sFilter.Append(" and c.Mobile").Append(" LIKE ").Append(_.Util.ToSqlLikeString(item.ToString()));
                    break;
                case "CountrySysNo":
                    sb.Append("a.CountrySysNo").Append("=").Append(item.ToString());
                    break;
                case "StateSysNo":
                    sb.Append("a.StateSysNo").Append("=").Append(item.ToString());
                    break;
                case "CitySysNo":
                    sb.Append("a.CitySysNo").Append("=").Append(item.ToString());
                    break;
                case "ZipCode":
                    sb.Append("a.ZipCode").Append(" LIKE ").Append(_.Util.ToSqlLikeString(item.ToString()));
                    break;
                case "Address":
                    sb.Append("a.Address").Append(" LIKE ").Append(_.Util.ToSqlLikeString(item.ToString()));
                    break;
                case "paymenTerm":
                    sb.Append("b.PaymentTermSysNo").Append("=").Append(item.ToString());
                    break;
                case "State":
                    sb.Append("a.State").Append(" LIKE ").Append(_.Util.ToSqlLikeString(item.ToString()));
                    break;
                case "City":
                    sb.Append("a.City").Append(" LIKE ").Append(_.Util.ToSqlLikeString(item.ToString()));
                    break;
                default:
                    if (item is int) sb.Append("a."+key).Append("=").Append(item.ToString());
                    else if (item is string) sb.Append("a."+key).Append(" LIKE ").Append(_.Util.ToSqlLikeString(item.ToString()));
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sb.ToString()))
            sql = sql.Replace("@filter", sFilter.ToString());
        else
            sql = "SELECT a.*,(select Country_Name from World_Country where SysNo=a.CountrySysNo) Country,case when StateIsString=1 then State else (select State_Name from World_State where SysNo=a.StateSysNo) end StateName,case when CityIsString=1 then City else (select City_Name from World_City where SysNo=a.CitySysNo) end CityName,b.CreditLimt,b.CurrentPaymentReceivable,(select top 1 c.repname from rep c where c.AccountSysNo=a.sysno) RepName,(select top 1 PaymentName from PaymentType where SysNo=b.PaymentTermSysNo) PaymentTerm FROM Account a left join PaymentTerm b on a.sysNo=b.AccountSysNo where 1=1";
        sb.Append(" and 1=1");
        sql = sql + sb.ToString();
        sql += " ORDER BY SysNo DESC";
        return SqlHelper.ExecuteDataSet(sql);
    }


    private void Map(DataRow tempdr)
    {
        SysNo = _.Util.ConvertToInt(tempdr["SysNo"]);
        AccountNo = _.Util.ConvertToString(tempdr["AccountNo"]);
        RegistDate = _.Util.ConvertToDateTime(tempdr["RegistDate"]);
        AccountName = _.Util.ConvertToString(tempdr["AccountName"]);
        PassWord = _.Util.ConvertToString(tempdr["PassWord"]);
        Status = _.Util.ConvertToInt(tempdr["Status"]);
        CountrySysNo = _.Util.ConvertToInt(tempdr["CountrySysNo"]);
        StateSysNo = _.Util.ConvertToInt(tempdr["StateSysNo"]);
        CitySysNo = _.Util.ConvertToInt(tempdr["CitySysNo"]);
        ZipCode = _.Util.ConvertToString(tempdr["ZipCode"]);
        Address=_.Util.ConvertToString(tempdr["Address"]);
        WebSite = _.Util.ConvertToString(tempdr["WebSite"]);
        Inputdate = _.Util.ConvertToDateTime(tempdr["Inputdate"]);
        LstInputdate = _.Util.ConvertToDateTime(tempdr["LstInputdate"]);
        Type = _.Util.ConvertToInt(tempdr["Type"]);
        ShipBy = _.Util.ConvertToInt(tempdr["ShipBy"]);
        StateIsString = Convert.ToBoolean(tempdr["StateIsString"]);
        CityIsString = Convert.ToBoolean(tempdr["CityIsString"]);
        State = _.Util.ConvertToString(tempdr["State"]);
        City = _.Util.ConvertToString(tempdr["City"]);
    }

    public int Insert()
    {
             if (_.Util.HasMoreRow(SqlHelper.ExecuteDataSet(string.Format("SELECT TOP 1 SYSNO FROM Account WHERE AccountName='{0}'", AccountName)))) throw new DataExistException("The Account Name Exists!");
        SysNo = SqlHelper.Insert("Account_Sequence");
        string sql = @"INSERT INTO Account(SysNo,AccountNo,RegistDate,AccountName,PassWord,Status,CountrySysNo,StateSysNo,CitySysNo,ZipCode,Address,WebSite,Inputdate,Type,ShipBy,StateIsString,CityIsString,State,City)VALUES(@SysNo,@AccountNo,@RegistDate,@AccountName,@PassWord,@Status,@CountrySysNo,@StateSysNo,@CitySysNo,@ZipCode,@Address,@WebSite,@Inputdate,@Type,@ShipBy,@StateIsString,@CityIsString,@State,@City)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql);
        SqlParameter paramSysNo = new SqlParameter("@SysNo", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
        SqlParameter paramAccountNo = new SqlParameter("@AccountNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        SqlParameter paramRegistDate = new SqlParameter("@RegistDate",SqlDbType.DateTime);
        SqlParameter paramAccountName = new SqlParameter("@AccountName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        SqlParameter paramPassWord = new SqlParameter("@PassWord", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        SqlParameter paramStatus = new SqlParameter("@Status", SqlDbType.Int);
        SqlParameter paramCountrySysNo = new SqlParameter("@CountrySysNo",SqlDbType.Int);
        SqlParameter paramStateSysNo = new SqlParameter("@StateSysNo", SqlDbType.Int);
        SqlParameter paramCitySysNo = new SqlParameter("@CitySysNo", SqlDbType.Int);
        SqlParameter paramZipCode = new SqlParameter("@ZipCode",SqlDbType.VarChar);
        SqlParameter paramAddress = new SqlParameter("@Address", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        SqlParameter paramWebSite = new SqlParameter("@WebSite",SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        SqlParameter paramInputdate = new SqlParameter("@Inputdate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        //SqlParameter paramLstInputdate = new SqlParameter("@LstInputdate",SqlDbType.DateTime);
        SqlParameter paramType = new SqlParameter("@Type",SqlDbType.TinyInt);
        SqlParameter paramShipBy = new SqlParameter("@ShipBy",SqlDbType.Int);
        SqlParameter paramStateIsString = new SqlParameter("@StateIsString", SqlDbType.Bit);
        SqlParameter paramCityIsString = new SqlParameter("@CityIsString", SqlDbType.Bit);

        SqlParameter paramState = new SqlParameter("@State", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        SqlParameter paramCity = new SqlParameter("@City", SqlDbType.VarChar);

        if (SysNo != _.Default.IntNull) paramSysNo.Value = SysNo;
        else paramSysNo.Value = DBNull.Value;
        if (AccountNo != _.Default.StringNull) paramAccountNo.Value = AccountNo;
        else paramAccountNo.Value = DBNull.Value;
        if (RegistDate != _.Default.DateTimeNull) paramRegistDate.Value = RegistDate;
        else paramRegistDate.Value = DBNull.Value;
        if (AccountName != _.Default.StringNull) paramAccountName.Value = AccountName;
        else paramAccountName.Value = DBNull.Value;
        if (PassWord != _.Default.StringNull) paramPassWord.Value = PassWord;
        else paramPassWord.Value = DBNull.Value;
        if (Status != _.Default.IntNull) paramStatus.Value = Status;
        else paramStatus.Value = DBNull.Value;
        if (CountrySysNo != _.Default.IntNull) paramCountrySysNo.Value = CountrySysNo;
        else paramCountrySysNo.Value = DBNull.Value;
        if (StateSysNo != _.Default.IntNull) paramStateSysNo.Value = StateSysNo;
        else paramStateSysNo.Value = DBNull.Value;
        if (CitySysNo != _.Default.IntNull) paramCitySysNo.Value = CitySysNo;
        else paramCitySysNo.Value = DBNull.Value;
        if (ZipCode != _.Default.StringNull) paramZipCode.Value = ZipCode;
        else paramZipCode.Value = DBNull.Value;
        if (Address != _.Default.StringNull) paramAddress.Value = Address;
        else paramAddress.Value = DBNull.Value;
        if (WebSite != _.Default.StringNull) paramWebSite.Value = WebSite;
        else paramWebSite.Value = DBNull.Value;
        if (Inputdate != _.Default.DateTimeNull) paramInputdate.Value = Inputdate;
        else paramInputdate.Value = DBNull.Value;

        //if (LstInputdate != _.Default.DateTimeNull) paramLstInputdate.Value = LstInputdate;
        //else paramLstInputdate.Value = DBNull.Value;

        if (Type != _.Default.IntNull) paramType.Value = Type;
        else paramType.Value = DBNull.Value;

        if (ShipBy != _.Default.IntNull) paramShipBy.Value =ShipBy;
        else paramShipBy.Value = DBNull.Value;

        paramStateIsString.Value = StateIsString;
        paramCityIsString.Value = CityIsString;

        if (State != _.Default.StringNull) paramState.Value = State;
        else paramState.Value = DBNull.Value;
        if (City != _.Default.StringNull) paramCity.Value = City;
        else paramCity.Value = DBNull.Value;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramSysNo);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramAccountNo);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramRegistDate);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramAccountName);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramPassWord);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramStatus);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCountrySysNo);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramStateSysNo);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCitySysNo);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramZipCode);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramAddress);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramWebSite);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramInputdate);

        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramType);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramShipBy);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramStateIsString);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCityIsString);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramState);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCity);
        SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
        return SysNo;
    }

    public int Update()
    {
        if (_.Util.HasMoreRow(SqlHelper.ExecuteDataSet(string.Format("SELECT TOP 1 SYSNO FROM Account WHERE AccountName='{0}' AND SYSNO<>{1}", AccountName, SysNo))))      throw new DataExistException("The Account Name Exists!");
             //string sql = "UPDATE Account SET AccountNo=@AccountNo,RegistDate=@RegistDate,AccountName=@AccountName,PassWord=@PassWord,Status=@Status,CountrySysNo=@CountrySysNo,StateSysNo=@StateSysNo,CitySysNo=@CitySysNo,ZipCode=@ZipCode,Address=@Address,WebSite=@WebSite,Inputdate=@Inputdate,LstInputdate=@LstInputdate,Type=@Type,ShipBy=@ShipBy WHERE SysNo=@SysNo";
             string sql = "UPDATE Account SET RegistDate=@RegistDate,AccountName=@AccountName,PassWord=@PassWord,Status=@Status,CountrySysNo=@CountrySysNo,StateSysNo=@StateSysNo,CitySysNo=@CitySysNo,ZipCode=@ZipCode,Address=@Address,WebSite=@WebSite,LstInputdate=@LstInputdate,Type=@Type,ShipBy=@ShipBy,StateIsString=@StateIsString,CityIsString=@CityIsString,State=@State,City=@City WHERE SysNo=@SysNo";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql);
        SqlParameter paramSysNo = new SqlParameter("@SysNo", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
        //SqlParameter paramAccountNo = new SqlParameter("@AccountNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        SqlParameter paramRegistDate = new SqlParameter("@RegistDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        SqlParameter paramAccountName = new SqlParameter("@AccountName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        SqlParameter paramPassWord = new SqlParameter("@PassWord", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        SqlParameter paramStatus = new SqlParameter("@Status", SqlDbType.Int);
        SqlParameter paramCountrySysNo = new SqlParameter("@CountrySysNo", SqlDbType.Int);
        SqlParameter paramStateSysNo = new SqlParameter("@StateSysNo", SqlDbType.Int);
        SqlParameter paramCitySysNo = new SqlParameter("@CitySysNo", SqlDbType.Int);
        SqlParameter paramZipCode = new SqlParameter("@ZipCode", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        SqlParameter paramAddress = new SqlParameter("@Address", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        SqlParameter paramWebSite = new SqlParameter("@WebSite", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        //SqlParameter paramInputdate = new SqlParameter("@Inputdate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        SqlParameter paramLstInputdate = new SqlParameter("@LstInputdate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        SqlParameter paramType = new SqlParameter("@Type", SqlDbType.TinyInt);
        SqlParameter paramShipBy = new SqlParameter("@ShipBy", SqlDbType.Int);
        SqlParameter paramStateIsString = new SqlParameter("@StateIsString", SqlDbType.Bit);
        SqlParameter paramCityIsString = new SqlParameter("@CityIsString", SqlDbType.Bit);

        SqlParameter paramState = new SqlParameter("@State", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        SqlParameter paramCity = new SqlParameter("@City", SqlDbType.VarChar);

        if (SysNo != _.Default.IntNull) paramSysNo.Value = SysNo;
        else paramSysNo.Value = DBNull.Value;
        //if (AccountNo != _.Default.StringNull) paramAccountNo.Value = AccountNo;
        //else paramAccountNo.Value = DBNull.Value;
        if (RegistDate != _.Default.DateTimeNull) paramRegistDate.Value = RegistDate;
        else paramRegistDate.Value = DBNull.Value;
        if (AccountName != _.Default.StringNull) paramAccountName.Value = AccountName;
        else paramAccountName.Value = DBNull.Value;
        if (PassWord != _.Default.StringNull) paramPassWord.Value = PassWord;
        else paramPassWord.Value = DBNull.Value;
        if (Status != _.Default.IntNull) paramStatus.Value = Status;
        else paramStatus.Value = DBNull.Value;
        if (CountrySysNo != _.Default.IntNull) paramCountrySysNo.Value = CountrySysNo;
        else paramCountrySysNo.Value = DBNull.Value;
        if (StateSysNo != _.Default.IntNull) paramStateSysNo.Value = StateSysNo;
        else paramStateSysNo.Value = DBNull.Value;
        if (CitySysNo != _.Default.IntNull) paramCitySysNo.Value = CitySysNo;
        else paramCitySysNo.Value = DBNull.Value;
        if (ZipCode != _.Default.StringNull) paramZipCode.Value = ZipCode;
        else paramZipCode.Value = DBNull.Value;
        if (Address != _.Default.StringNull) paramAddress.Value = Address;
        else paramAddress.Value = DBNull.Value;
        if (WebSite != _.Default.StringNull) paramWebSite.Value = WebSite;
        else paramWebSite.Value = DBNull.Value;
        //if (Inputdate != _.Default.DateTimeNull) paramInputdate.Value = Inputdate;
        //else paramInputdate.Value = DBNull.Value;

        if (LstInputdate != _.Default.DateTimeNull) paramLstInputdate.Value = LstInputdate;
        else paramLstInputdate.Value = DBNull.Value;

        if (Type != _.Default.IntNull) paramType.Value = Type;
        else paramType.Value = DBNull.Value;

        if (ShipBy != _.Default.IntNull) paramShipBy.Value = ShipBy;
        else paramShipBy.Value = DBNull.Value;

        paramStateIsString.Value = StateIsString;
        paramCityIsString.Value = CityIsString;

        if (State != _.Default.StringNull) paramState.Value = State;
        else paramState.Value = DBNull.Value;
        if (City != _.Default.StringNull) paramCity.Value = City;
        else paramCity.Value = DBNull.Value;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramSysNo);
        //cmd.Parameters.Add(paramAccountNo);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramRegistDate);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramAccountName);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramPassWord);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramStatus);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCountrySysNo);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramStateSysNo);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCitySysNo);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramZipCode);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramAddress);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramWebSite);

        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramLstInputdate);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramType);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramShipBy);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramStateIsString);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCityIsString);

        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramState);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCity);
        return SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
    }

         public void Delete(string SysNo)
         {
             string sSql = "delete from Account where sysno=" + SysNo;
             SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(sSql);
         }

     }
 }
```

The following code is how I update using this method:

```
 SAccount oinfo = _.SAccount.GetItem(SysNo); //I get a specific row from database
 oinfo.AccountNo = txtAccountNo.Text.Trim(); //assign a value
```

I keep assigning until it satisfy update() then I do this:

```
 oinfo.Update();
```

And I use Strongly typed datasets:
[image]

This is how i execute my Strongly typed datasets:

```
  DatabaseSQL.DataSet1TableAdapters.ProductImageTableAdapter InsertProductImageQuery;

  InsertProductImageQuery = new DatabaseSQL.DataSet1TableAdapters.ProductImageTableAdapter();

  InsertProductImageQuery.InsertProductImage(GlobalProductNo, ImageIDx, ImageNamex, TodayxUpload, null, null, null, NewSysnoPI, path);
```

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: You'll probably get better answers if you include the code to show how you're inserting the data, how you're getting the identity of the inserted data, and how you're displaying it back to the user.

Comment: Do not put code in comments, update your question with the code.

Comment: I have updated my question with the code and added a picture for my dataset. Within my dataset, I use the same style as shown in the picture with all my tables/query in my dataset